# How can i send POST data (GCM registration id)

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, drupal-7, push-notification

I have created my web service with following this instruction: http://www.danielhanold.com/story/drupal-7-push-notifications-how-to-register-a-device-token-using-services

I am using phonegap for creating mobile app. And now I want to build an push notification server for my new app.

I have registered with this code fragment:

```
var pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
    pushNotification.register(app.successHandler, app.errorHandler,{"senderID":"XXXXXXXXXXXX","ecb":"app.onNotificationGCM"});
```

Then I get register id and trying to send my web service with this code fragment:

```
onNotificationGCM: function(e) {
    switch( e.event )
    {
        case 'registered':
            if ( e.regid.length > 0 )
            {
                console.log("Regid " + e.regid);

                var postData = { token: e.regid , type: "android"};

                alert( JSON.stringify( postData ) );

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: "text",
                    data: JSON.stringify( postData ),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: 'http://www.my-domain.com/mobiledata/push_notifications',
                    success: function(){
                        //console.log(data);
                        alert('Your comment was successfully added');
                    },
                    error: function(){
                        //console.log(data);
                        alert('There was an error adding your comment');
                    }
                });
            }
        break;

        case 'message':
          // this is the actual push notification. its format depends on the data model from the push server
          alert('message = '+e.message+' msgcnt = '+e.msgcnt);
        break;

        case 'error':
          alert('GCM error = '+e.msg);
        break;

        default:
          alert('An unknown GCM event has occurred');
          break;
    }
},
```

Actually I found all this code fragment by searching many hours and attempts. But I have some problems. First of all my app gets a registration id via pushNotification plugin of phonegap and I get alert but after trying post data with ajax any alert message doesn't shown. In my opinion a success message or error message must be shown.

On the other hand, all permissions are added to AndroidManifest.xml file. Other parts of my app is running well such as getting data showing pages and interaction with web.

Comment: do you see something on the logcat? can you do try the post to your server alone to see if it's a problem with the communication with the server or some other thing

Comment: Sorry, i have a little doubt about your code, why you  use ECB object to manage the registration success and not the succes callback instead? [docs](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin#ecb-amazon-fire-os-android-and-ios) about the error, are you sure that you don't have any king of CORS or entworking problem? It seems that your ajax not start or stop immediatly.